# Code needed to group rows in a pandas datadrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string, grouping

I have an excel dataset with 9000 rows(samples) and 3000 columns(features). Each row has an id (e.g. C4) at the end of its name. Any help on how to group these ids?

I tried using the group by function but it wouldn’t accept the keywords C1 - C6

Comment: id at the end of its name. the name is in which column

Comment: A specific minimal example in the form of a reproducible DataFrame would be required to answer